# elasticsearch - trying to find latest time stamp in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have written a query in elastic search using range on a timestamp field.  I need to find the latest timestamp for each group.  First I perform the query, then group by the name field, then try to select the latest timestamp.  But it is not working.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Below is my json I use for the search Post query from postman

{
  "query" : {
        "range" : { "timestamp" :  { "gte" :"2016-10-05T15:00:35", "lte" :   "2016-10-06T15:10:35" } } 
    },

```
"aggs" : {
   "groupbyname" : { 
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "name"
            },  
            "aggs" : {
                "selectlatesttimestamp" :  {
                "max" : {
                    "field" : "timestamp"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [top-hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation to do that, as per your example, you could do something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2016-10-05T15:00:35",
        "lte": "2016-10-06T15:10:35"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupbyname": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_group_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you're not using the actual results originating from the query, but only use the aggregations, you can also add `"size":0` to the top level object (above the `"query"`).

If you only need some of the fields, you could include a `_source` section to your top hits aggregation, for example if you only need to get the latest timestamp you could do something like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "2016-10-05T15:00:35",
        "lte": "2016-10-06T15:10:35"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupbyname": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_group_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": [
              "timestamp"
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should work, but for some reason it is still  returning multiple documents with the same name in the that time range.  I am wondering if it is something else with the manner we have defined timestamp or mapped it.  Here is the JSON for how we defined "name" and "timestamp"  nothing unusual ...       "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          }

Comment: This is how I get my result set: https://jsonblob.com/57f69a7ee4b0bcac9f7b677d which looks ok to me, I get 1 document per group with the latest timestamp. It's important to note that your `name` field should also be set to `"index": "not_analyzed"` otherwise Elasticsearch will tokenize the content and might create extra buckets, so if you have a doc with `name: "new york"` it will show two buckets, one for "new" and one for "york".